# How to fetch a video from db in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'am trying this Code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>   
<source src="<?php echo 'resource/video/';  echo $image; ?>" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="<?php echo 'resource/video/';  echo $image; ?>" type="video/ogg">    </video>
```

Comment: Yes and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html if v2

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html if v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base_url() like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>   
             <source src="<?php echo base_url('resource/video/'.$image); ?>" type="video/mp4">
             <source src="<?php echo base_url('resource/video/'.$image);   ?>" type="video/ogg">
```